# Can't import requests in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm having problem importing requests in views.py. I've already installed requests in the environment and I already checked through Django shell by importing requests and there was no error. But every time I import requests in views.py I get the error ModuleNotFoundError. Can anyone help me.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.http import HttpResponse
import json 
import requests
#from matplotlib.style import context


# Create your views here.
# Think of views as a place to handle your various 
# web pages we are going to do this with either 
# functions based view or class basesd view

def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    print (args, kwargs)
    print ("This is the request")
    print ("Request has been Sent")

    putdata = {"supplier_name": "Django", "supplier_contact": "8000", "supplier_address": "America", "supplier_email": "Django@gmail.com", "supplier_state": "New York", "supplier_country": "America"}
    post = requests.post("http://localhost:8085/api/supplier", json=putdata)
    print(post.text)
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>") # string of HTML code
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

Error Message:

```
File 
from products.views import test_view
  File "C:\Users\Fakhr\Desktop\trydjango\products\views.py", line 2, in 
<module>
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I'm new to Django so forgive the messy code, I'm just trying various things in order to see how they work.

Comment: Do you use the same python.exe to execute the script ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a folder named `requests`(without __init__.py file) in the root directory of you project.

Comment: @Devyl It's the same version 3.10.4

Comment: @SandeepRawat I don't have a requests folder.

Comment: can you show your error fully?

Comment: execute command `pip freeze` in your console, and make sure `requests` is in it's output, if it is not, it means you didn't install `requests`

Comment: you can try also `pip3 install requests` it will install for python3

Comment: @oruchkin I did pip freeze. requests==2.27.1, as for pip3 same output requirement already satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you have started your Django project in virtual environment? If you have a virtual environment, can you check *requests* module is installed with `pip3 show requests` after activating it?

Example scenario:

```
#install venv 
python3 -m venv venv

#activate venv
source venv/bin/activate

#on Windows (cmd.exe)
venv\Scripts\activate.bat

#on Windows (PowerShell)
venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1

#install requests in virtual environment
pip install request
```

Also if the PATH for pip is not set up on your machine, replace pip with python3 -m pip:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

If PIP Path exists like this:

```
pip3 show requests
```

Otherwise:

```
python3 -m pip show requests
```

Finally, make sure you choose the right interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't installed the required package. Try this in your terminal:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: As I have stated in my question I have already installed requests using pip command. Both normally and in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you are running the script in the installed environment.

Comment: As I have stated in my question I have already installed requests using pip command. Both normally and in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this in the list of apps installed in the project's settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Add this...
    'requests',
]
```

Comment: this is wrong, i never did this with requests library, request must work without it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from Django Tutorial in Visual Studio Code official Docs. Turns out instead of pip install requests. I need to do python -m pip install requests.